# Show atributte of an specific object searching by id with angular

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose

I am recent in angular... I have a list of data that are shown in a view by a table. I need to show in one of the columns the "description" attribute of each of the objects in the array "availableProducts"

Example of data:

```
availableProducts = [
    {"sending":true,"id":"8c94a40561b6d76243bea11f","cod":"123ABC","description":"Description 1","dateUpd":"2019-03-22T08:59:17.996Z","__v":0},
    {"sending":false,"id":"8ca378ee413da0715b5b48d6","cod":"987ZYX","description":"Description 2","dateUpd":"2019-04-25T08:23:11.286Z","__v":0},
    {"sending":false,"id":"8bc07055cb116b1698d4b1be","cod":"000AAA","description":"Description 3","dateUpd":"2019-04-24T14:18:29.378Z","__v":0},
    {"sending":false,"id":"8ac16e5564169a5233db4456","cod":"111BBB","description":"Description 4","dateUpd":"2019-04-25T08:22:23.456Z","__v":0}
]
```

I need to search for id, since this value is different in each row of data, in my table that value corresponds to "invoice.product" that shows the id of the product object.
To understand this I give you an example of the model "Invoice" in mongoose:

```
{
  "id" : ObjectId("5cb5811ffb5c03579281e22f"),
  "name": "string",
  "number": "671782",
  "contractId": "C8282",
  "product": {
    "id": ObjectId("8c94a40561b6d76243bea11f"),
    "sending": true,
    "cod":"123ABC",
    "description":"Description 1",
    "dateUpd":"2019-03-22T08:59:17.996Z"
  },
  "url": "string",
  "__v" : 0
}
```

What I have so far to show is this, but it shows me all the descriptions and I want you to look for the specific description by id, how can I do it?

```
<td class="text-center">
     <div class="badge" ng-repeat="prod in availableProducts | filter: invoice.product">{{ prod.description }}</div>
</td>
```

Comment: Are you getting `invoice.product` correctly?

Comment: Yes, the value of invoice.product is the value of id (for example: "8c94a40561b6d76243bea11f")

Comment: So you want to show description when product id matches invoice.product right? Try the answer below and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with mongoose. But I think this might solve your issue,

```
<td class="text-center">
     <div class="badge" *ngFor="let prod of availableProducts" [hidden]="prod.id!=invoice.product">
         {{ prod.description }}
     </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Works perfectly!! It solved my problem, thanks!! :)